# If Statement - if current post is a child of a post with a taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types

We have a custom posts that has parents and multiple child posts. The parent is assigned to a taxonomy but not the child.

I need if statement to determine if the post is a child of a parent with a taxonomy called home-theater

Comment: Is `home-theater` a taxonomy itself, or a specific term in a taxonomy?

Comment: The taxonomy is projector-types. home-theater is a slug.

Answer (score 1):

This will get all custom post `ctp_slug` assigned to any term of `home-theater` taxonomy and return array with posts ID. `post__in` parameter will limit results to only post with given ID.

```
$args=[
    'post_type' => 'ctp_slug',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'offset' => 0,
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'home-theater',
            'operator' => 'EXISTS',
        ]
    ],
    'post__in' => [parent_ID],
];
$result = get_posts($args);
```

**Edit #1**

```
function get_sidebar_ads_above_tabs_conditional()
{
    global $post;
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_has_tax = (!empty($parent) 
        && has_term('home-theater', 'projector_types', $parent))

    $returnValue = '<div style="margin-top: 20px;">';
    if ($parent_has_tax)
    {
        $returnValue .= '<div>Banner Ad 1</div>';
    } else
    {
        $returnValue .= '<div>Banner Ad 1</div>';
    } $returnValue .= '</div>';
    return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: add_shortcode('get-sidebar-ads-above-tabs-conditional', 'get_sidebar_ads_above_tabs_conditional');
function get_sidebar_ads_above_tabs_conditional() {  
 global $post;
$returnValue = '<div style="margin-top: 20px;">';
    
if (has_term('home-theater', 'projector_types', $post->ID)) {
$returnValue .= '<div>Banner Ad 1</div>';
}
[need if statement here to display Banner Ad 1, if the page is a child of page has tax slug home-theater for projector types]
else {
$returnValue .= '<div>Banner Ad 3</div>';
}
$returnValue .= '</div>';
return $returnValue;
}

Comment: Here is the short code we create to display banner ads. it works but we need to add another if statement to display a specific banner the page is a child of a page assigned to home-theater for taxonomy called projector_types.